# Conditional settings in Vim whether command is in system path

Tags: vim

How do I make conditional settings in vim based on whether some command is available in system path?

For example I would like to enable par paragraph formating when the par command is available

Something like this:

```
if syspathhas("par")
    set formatprg=par\ -w80
endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `executable` function, as

```
if executable("par")
    set formatprg=par\ -w80
endif
```